приложение ключ pepk jks
что делать помогите пж делал все по гайду https://yandex.ru/video/preview/9948503358292896577 но дальше эта ошибка
В русторе пишут
(Для Windows) Перед использованием утилиты keytool предварительно перейдите в каталог bin установленной Java. Ваш путь и версия Java могут отличаться:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin"
нечего не понял типо надо скачать и установить keytool
вот картинка что у меня в терминале
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/2nyrPNviyvowTQ

На вашем скриншоте внизу на желтом фоне написан ответ. Используйте Java 11, а не 8.


У тебя написано, что программа была скомпилирована более новой версией Java, ну точнее её код - 55, а у тебя поддерживает только до 52.
Тут можешь посмотреть таблицу в виде версия-код: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers
Короче обнови Java хотябы до версии 11
